# Yosemite Terminal weirdly says Meia:/

Tags: macos, terminal

My Yosemite Terminal App say "Meia:/ username$"?

I don't know what **Meia** stands for.

Normally I would expect something else. Can I change it?

Comment: if you don't know why it's there, then why do you expect something different to be there? BTW it's usually the host name.

Comment: No Idea why it sais that... Maybe some program with sudo rights changed it. Thank you for the tipp though.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something other than programming.  Try http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ran this command and it changed to **MYHOSTNAME**.

```
sudo scutil --set HostName MYHOSTNAME.local
```

Comment: What?  you changed the name of the computer cos you didn't like it in the terminal?  What's wrong with configuring `$PS1`?  What has this got to do with programming?

Comment: Somebody else changed it beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

That is the name given to your computer!

Change it here, no need for terminal command.

System Preferences > Sharing

Change your Computer Name here.